# change params[:link] before @link.save

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to change a value which I get from an input field before I save it.

```
params[:link]['url'] = "www.facebook.com/redbull"
```

Now I just want to put "redbull" in the database. The following code fails because it changes the `params[:link]` before validation. I want to execute it after a valid validation.

```
def create
    url = params[:link]['url'].split('facebook.com/').last
    params[:link]['url'] = url
    @link = Link.new(params[:link])


    if @link.save
      flash[:success] = 'Link was successfully created.'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance

**Now it works, thx to caley:**

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save(:on => :create) do
    self.url = self.url.split('facebook.com/').last 
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd vote for trying a before_save or after_validation callback in the model to run a custom method you create. You could also add (:on => :create) to the before_save callback so it doesn't run on update.

Something like

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :clean_link

def clean_link
  self.link = self.link.split('facebook.com/').last 
end
```

Be sure to setup any getters or setters for accessing link if need be. I did something similar in a rails 3 app I've done a bit of work on [here](https://github.com/caleywoods/rubeddit/blob/master/app/models/link.rb)

Comment: Thx caley, works perfectly! your link to your git rep is also very helpfull!

Comment: Glad to hear Lukas, you can also thank rajasaur. He had the same type of answer just not as fleshed out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the "after_validations" callback to do the change? This should be called post validation and before the save is called.

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M000065

Answer (score 0):

```
@link = Link.new(:link => url)
```

or

```
@link = Link.new
@link.link = url
```

I am assuming the attribute to which you want save 'redbull' is named link in the above code.

Comment: '@link' is a hash with the 'params[:link]' values and I want to change 'params[:link]['url']'. I am first validating 'url' and then I want to store only the 'redbull'part and therefor I need so split.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `delete` method of the Hash to remove the key `:link` and manually set the link attribute.

Like after validation, if the object is `valid?` you can say `params.delete(:link)` not before taking it into a variable for ex. `@uri = params[:link]['url']`.

The code might look like this:

```
def create
  url = params[:link]['url'].split('facebook.com/').last
  @link = Link.new(params[:link])
  if @link.valid?
    @link.url = url

    @link.save

    flash[:success] = 'Link was successfully created.'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This method is not tested, but might work.

**Update:**
Like I said, this is one of the ways you can do this. Other way is to employ any of the call back methods like before_save or after_validation.